# What would happen if a 3D game used Bitmaps to render, instead of vertices and textures?

Tags: opengl, 3d, graphics, rendering

What would happen if a 3D game used Bitmaps to render, instead of vertices and textures?

Comment: I don't understand the question - what do you expect to happen? And how do you plan to describe 3D models using only bitmaps?

Comment: Do you mean voxels?

Comment: I mean, would normal sprites be able to replace player models

Comment: You mean 2D sprites? Like in old and retro games? Because you still haven't explained how you intend to describe full 3D models using only bitmaps

Comment: So, do you mean like Doom, Heretic, etc...?

Comment: Yes. i mean would normal sprites and such be capable enough to render a 3D game

Comment: 2D sprites are not 3D, so I really don't understand what you are trying to get at.

Comment: Yes, but in the end after the Vertex shader does its thing it Rasterizes the 3D image and eventually turns it into a 2D image. Im trying to ask if Bitmaps can be used in 3D games to store information about each pixel such as how vertices do. ( Im sorry if i sound confusing. i have no idea how to bring it out of my head haha )

Comment: So you want to store vertex information in bitmaps? It's possible, but I don't see how that would "replace" vertices. Otherwise I have doubts you fully understand how the rendering pipeline works.

Comment: I meant, would there be a big difference in rendering using Bitmaps and yes i know very little about the graphics pipeline. Thanks for answering :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible to use a 2D API to get a 3D effect. I have done so in past by implementing my own code for 3D to 2D projection (using transformation matrices) and a 2D API capable of rendering polygons. Yet, I was projecting the points of the polygon point by point, and I did have 3D coordinates for the points... so weren’t they vertex?

This is the technique used by StarFox for SNES:

[image: StarFox screen capture]

Remember that SNES didn't have native support for 3D.

---

My initial guess was you did mean voxels because you could bitmaps to define a 3D voxel model... this is often used when dealing with 3D scan or 3D printing, for example:

[image: example of 3D scan]

You can represent a voxel model as a 3D array, that could be stored as a bitmap. For example, multiple layers of an FMRI scan...

[image: FMRI scan layers]

...can be composed to create a 3D model:

[image: 3D Model of the head]

---

Another thing you can do is create sprites from a pre-rendered 3D model or even photos of physical objects, that was common in old games. For example the following image is from ClayFighter:

[image: ClayFighter screen capture]

In the image, the monsters are 2D sprites.

There are also example that use 2D (camera facing) sprites in 3D environments:

Hexen (look at the monsters)

[image: Hexen screen capture]

Mario 64 (look at the trees)

[image: Mario64 screen capture]

Populous: The Beginning (look at the people)

[image: Populous screen capture]

---

Finally, when loading 3D models to the graphic card, you are loading a large array of numbers. You will either hard code those numbers, compute them on the fly, or more likely load them from a 3D model file... nothing is preventing you from taking them from an image file, reading the colors of the pixels as the coordinates in the model. That's certainly something you can do.

One particular example of this is using an image as height map, in that case the X and Y coordinates of the pixels are the X and Y in the terrain, and the luminosity of the pixels is used as height (Z) for the terrain, for example:

[image: Height map demonstration]

---

Will any of these replace vertex? Pff, no. These are tools, tricks if you like, that you may combine to get the results you one with the restrictions you have.

Comment: Thanks man, that was a great explanation, sorry i cant "+1"

Comment: You should be a Microsoft Certified Software Developer

Comment: @Good hey, I am... even mention it on my profile.

Comment: Ik, haha. Whole point i said it haha

Comment: SNES had a way to draw polygonal graphics with the super fx chip.

Comment: @Thearot It did the same as OpenGL do with the only difference that it didn't use a depth buffer due to memory limitation

Comment: @Bálint I didn't claim SNES don't have a way to render polygons, I did claim it was 2D. I'm convinced the Super FX Chip is 2D because it doesn't reserve registers for Z position but it does for X, Y. I haven't done development for it, yet by looking at the intruction set it doesn't seem to do the perspective projection. I stay by claim that it is 2D. Edit: there is no instruction taking Z either.

Comment: This is a great answer to a bad, confusing, question of a beginner.

Comment: @Theraot neither does OpenGL. You need to do the matrix calculations yourself. OpenGL only divides with the `w` component. You could do the same thing with the superFX, you can store the positions as 3d vectors and only pass the projected vector's x and y coordinatwe.

Comment: @Bálint I'll guess you say that because in modern OpenGL there is no projection matrix anymore, instead you do whatever in the fragment shader (and even there I don't need to worry about matrix * vector is computed, and even if I had, it would be running on the GPU). So I do it "myself". I don't understand why you claim this chip is the same than OpenGL by pulling an example of something the chip can't do (load shaders). Btw old OpenGL handled projection from the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

You must use vertices, because the GPU only draws triangles, and you need to define those somehow.

The closest to bitmap based rendering are billboards. Some 3d games use 2d planes always oriented towards the camera to give the illusion if a 3d model (for example every sphere in super mario 64). But those still require a plane model to be present.

You need to define a 3d model somehow, and bitmaps aren't sufficient for this.

Comment: @Good if the answer is correct, press the tick symbol next to the answer

Comment: @Good you need to press the green tick, not the up arrow

Comment: Any stuff that appears to be 3D, is either or a photo, or a raytraced voxel cloud or vertex/texture.. Or something isomorphic to one of these XD

Comment: @GameDeveloper 1.) You have an amazing name 2.) You need to have some models anyway, though a way to "shade" the air would be cool

Comment: ahaha thanks :D Yeah, if you need to shade pixels from "thin air" then a SVG renderer is what you need.

Comment: @GameDev Or just scan through the air with planes.